# Is a rogue access point the same as a fake access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, 802.11

Is a rogue access point simply an additional access point inserted into a network? Is it distinctly different from an access point which is trying to spoof another official access point?

Comment: Your question is rather vague and open ended per the [faq]. Is this question based on an actual problem you have? If so, please provide more details.

Comment: Sorry. That sounded harsh. Not saying your question is not worth answering, it just doesn't seem you put much effort into researching yourself. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_AP) out.

Answer (score 2):

Rogue access points are setup by rogues; e.g., they are malicious.  Fake access points are not the real access point for whatever reason; e.g., set up by a rogue or by an administrator as a honeypot.